# How to add lines to a levelplot made using lattice (abline somehow not working)?

Tags: r, lattice

I want to draw horizontal and vertical lines on my level plot corresponding to x values from 74 to 76 and y values from 28 to 32.  Below is my R code. But when I run the following,I get the levelplots but no lines. I also recieve no error from R. The default theme on my installation is something which maps the values to pink and cyan. I have also tried using the panel function but no luck with that as well.

```
levelplot(d_fire_count_nom ~ longitude + latitude | factor(day)+factor(year), 
          data = asia,
          subset = (month == 10),  aspect="iso", contour = FALSE, layout=c(1,1), 
          main="If a fire occured in a region (low confidence) in October during 2001-2008", 
          scales=list(x=list(at=seq(from=60,to=98, by=1)), 
                      y=list(at=seq(from=5,to=38,by=1)),cex=.7, alternating=3), 
          xlim=c(60, 98), ylim=c(5, 38),
          abline=list(h=74:76, v=28:32, col="grey"))
```

Answer (score 7):

That's not how `lattice` graphics work. In fact, if you read `?levelplot` you'll see that there is no argument to that function called `abline`, so I'm not sure where you got that syntax from.

You add things to `lattice` graphics by altering the `panel` function. There are many `panel.*` functions for doing various things, like plotting points, lines, scatterplot smoothers, etc. In this case there's a `panel.abline` that we'd like to use. So we define our own `panel` function.

This uses the very first example from `?levelplot`:

```
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length.out = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
levelplot(z~x*y, grid,
        panel = function(...){
            panel.levelplot(...)
            panel.abline(h = 2.5)
            panel.abline(v = 2.5)
        }, 
        cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
        ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
        colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE)
```

Our new panel function needs to first draw the levelplot, so we have it call `panel.levelplot` first. Then we want to add some lines, so we add `panel.abline` for that purpose.

Comment: @Ridhima The code runs fine for me. I think something is going wrong with the way you are copy+paste-ing it that is introducing unusual characters.

Comment: @ Joran I am stuck:(   levelplot(d_fire_count_high ~ longitude + latitude | factor(day)+factor(year), data = asia, 
                      panel = function(...){
                      panel.levelplot(...)
                      panel.abline(h = 74)             
                      panel.abline(v = 28)        
                      }, 
subset = (month == 10),  aspect="iso", contour = FALSE, layout=c(1,1), main="If a fire occured in a region (high confidence) in October during 2001-2008", scales=list(x=list(at=seq(from=60,to=98, by=1)), y=list(at=seq(from=5,to=38, by=1)),cex=.7, alternating=3))

Comment: when I run the above, I get no error but no lines as well. Your code indeed runs perfectly fine. If there is a better way for showing my code to you please let me know.

Comment: @Ridhima You specify that your x scale goes from 60-98 and your y scale to go from 5-38 but you want a vertical line at 28 and a horizontal line at 74? Try plotting lines that actually fall _inside_ your desired plot region.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't even know what to say for the silly mistake made by me. I will be more careful in the future. Thanks a lot.