# How to add horizontal line to xy plot in lattice

Tags: r, lattice

I'm using lattice to generate a plot that looks like the image below

The code I'm using to generate the plot is:

```
xyplot(RMSE ~ Dimensions, data=afterdim,groups = paste("", Dim_Reduction),
type = "l", auto.key =list(spline = "bottom", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE), 
xlab="Dimensions", ylab="RMSE",scales=list(ylim=c(0,1)))
```

I would like to draw a horizontal line on this graph at `y-axis 0.23` with a different color. Purpose of adding the horizontal line is to show a baseline. Is this possible to do?

[image]

Sample data I'm using to plot is:

```
Dim_Reduction, Dimensions, Time, RMSE
PCA, 9, 15.39, 0.287
PCA, 8, 16.84, 0.290
PCA, 7, 14.13, 0.289
PCA, 6, 12.14, 0.292
PCA, 5, 12.54, 0.293
PCA, 4, 11.23, 0.295
ICA, 11, 20.23, 0.287
ICA, 10, 20.88, 0.288
ICA, 9, 16.34, 0.290
ICA, 8, 16.99, 0.294
ICA, 7, 14.34, 0.291
ICA, 6, 13.33, 0.292
ICA, 5, 12.12, 0.294
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add lines to a levelplot made using lattice (abline somehow not working)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622041/how-to-add-lines-to-a-levelplot-made-using-lattice-abline-somehow-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to read both ?xyplot section on 'scales' and ?llines:

```
mylattice <- xyplot(RMSE ~ Dimensions, data=afterdim, groups = Dim_Reduction,
            panel =function(x,y,groups,...){ 
                           panel.xyplot(x,y,groups,...);
                           panel.lines(x=3:12, y=rep(0.23,10), col="red") },
             scales=list( y=list( limits= c(0.22,0.3))),
             type = "l", xlab="Dimensions", ylab="RMSE")
 png(); print(mylattice); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Looking at this great example I finally understood panels and xyplots. Thanks!

Comment: I had just gotten to the point where I thought I had a working knowledge of lattice/Trellis graphics when ggplot came alone and I was lost again. (I remain mostly lost w.r.t. the gg-verse.)

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code

```
# data
afterdim <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Dim_Reduction  Dimensions  Time RMSE
PCA, 9, 15.39, 0.287
PCA, 8, 16.84, 0.290
PCA, 7, 14.13, 0.289
PCA, 6, 12.14, 0.292
PCA, 5, 12.54, 0.293
PCA, 4, 11.23, 0.295
ICA, 11, 20.23, 0.287
ICA, 10, 20.88, 0.288
ICA, 9, 16.34, 0.290
ICA, 8, 16.99, 0.294
ICA, 7, 14.34, 0.291
ICA, 6, 13.33, 0.292
ICA, 5, 12.12, 0.294")

xyplot(RMSE ~ Dimensions, data=afterdim,groups =  Dim_Reduction,
       type = c("l", "g"), auto.key =list(spline = "bottom", points = FALSE, lines = TRUE), 
       xlab="Dimensions", ylab="RMSE",scales=list(ylim=c(0,1)),
       panel=function(...) {
           panel.xyplot(...)
           panel.abline(h=.29)
       })
```

Comment: Great, this works. However, the line doesn't show when I put it on 0.23 because Y axis doesn't cover it. Is there a way to move the y-axis so that point would show?

Comment: You can use the solution of @BondedDust with `scales = list( y=list( limits= c(0.22,0.3)))` or replace it with   `ylim = c(0.22, 0.3)`