# Adding plotstick-like arrows to a scatterplot

Tags: r, levelplot

This is my first post here, thought i have read a lot of your Q&A these last 6 months. I'm currently working on ADCP (Aquatic Doppler Current Profiler) data, handled by the "oce" package from Dan Kelley (a little bit of advertising for those who want to deal with oceanographic datas in R). I'm not very experienced in R, and i have read the question relative to abline for levelplot functions ["How to add lines to a levelplot made using lattice (abline somehow not working)?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7622041/1815321).

What i currently have is a levelplot representing a time series of echo intensity (from backscattered signal, which is monitored in the same time as current is) data taken in 10m of depth, this 10m depth line is parted into 25 rows, where each measurement is done along the line. (see the code part to obtain an image of what i have)

(unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to post images).
I then proceed to generate an other plot, which represents arrows of the current direction as:

- The length of each arrow gives an indication of the current strength
- Its orientation is represented (all of this is done by taking the two components of the current intensity (East-West / North-South) and represent the resulting current).
- There is an arrow drawn for each tick of time (thus for the 1000 columns of my example data, there are always two components of the current intensity).
- Those arrows are drawn at the beginning of each measurement cell, thus at each row of my data, allowing to have a representation of currents for the whole water column.
  You can see the code part to have a "as i have" representation of currents

The purpose of this question is to understand how i can superimpose those two representations, drawing my current arrows at each row of the represented data, thus making a representation of both current direction, intensity and echo intensity.
Here i can't find any link to describe what i mean, but this is something i have already seen.

I tried with the panel function which seems to be the best option, but my knowledge of R and the handeling of this kind of work is small, and i hope one of you may have the time and the knowledges to help me to solve this problem way faster than i could.
I am, of course, available to answer any questions or give precisions. I may ask a lot more, after working on a large code for 6 months, my thirst for learning is now large.

Code to represent data :
Here are some data to represent what I have:
U (north/south component of velocity) and V (East/west):

```
U1= c(0.043,0.042,0.043,0.026,0.066,-0.017,-0.014,-0.019,0.024,-0.007,0.000,-0.048,-0.057,-0.101,-0.063,-0.114,-0.132,-0.103,-0.080,-0.098,-0.123,-0.087,-0.071,-0.050,-0.095,-0.047,-0.031,-0.028,-0.015,0.014,-0.019,0.048,0.026,0.039,0.084,0.036,0.071,0.055,0.019,0.059,0.038,0.040,0.013,0.044,0.078,0.040,0.098,0.015,-0.009,0.013,0.038,0.013,0.039,-0.008,0.024,-0.004,0.046,-0.004,-0.079,-0.032,-0.023,-0.015,-0.001,-0.028,-0.030,-0.054,-0.071,-0.046,-0.029,0.012,0.016,0.049,-0.020,0.012,0.016,-0.021,0.017,0.013,-0.008,0.057,0.028,0.056,0.114,0.073,0.078,0.133,0.056,0.057,0.096,0.061,0.096,0.081,0.100,0.092,0.057,0.028,0.055,0.025,0.082,0.087,0.070,-0.010,0.024,-0.025,0.018,0.016,0.007,0.020,-0.031,-0.045,-0.009,-0.060,-0.074,-0.072,-0.082,-0.100,-0.047,-0.089,-0.074,-0.070,-0.070,-0.070,-0.075,-0.070,-0.055,-0.078,-0.039,-0.050,-0.049,0.024,-0.026,-0.021,0.008,-0.026,-0.018,0.002,-0.009,-0.025,0.029,-0.040,-0.006,0.055,0.018,-0.035,-0.011,-0.026,-0.014,-0.006,-0.021,-0.031,-0.030,-0.056,-0.034,-0.026,-0.041,-0.107,-0.069,-0.082,-0.091,-0.096,-0.043,-0.038,-0.056,-0.068,-0.064,-0.042,-0.064,-0.058,0.016,-0.041,0.018,-0.008,0.058,0.006,0.007,0.060,0.011,0.050,-0.028,0.023,0.015,0.083,0.106,0.057,0.096,0.055,0.119,0.145,0.078,0.090,0.110,0.087,0.098,0.092,0.050,0.068,0.042,0.059,0.030,-0.005,-0.005,-0.013,-0.013,-0.016,0.008,-0.045,-0.021,-0.036,0.020,-0.018,-0.032,-0.038,0.021,-0.077,0.003,-0.010,-0.001,-0.024,-0.020,-0.022,-0.029,-0.053,-0.022,-0.007,-0.073,0.013,0.018,0.002,-0.038,0.024,0.025,0.033,0.008,0.016,-0.018,0.023,-0.001,-0.010,0.006,0.053,0.004,0.001,-0.003,0.009,0.019,0.024,0.031,0.024,0.009,-0.009,-0.035,-0.030,-0.031,-0.094,-0.006,-0.052,-0.061,-0.104,-0.098,-0.054,-0.161,-0.110,-0.078,-0.178,-0.052,-0.073,-0.051,-0.065,-0.029,-0.012,-0.053,-0.070,-0.040,-0.056,-0.004,-0.032,-0.065,-0.005,0.036,0.023,0.043,0.078,0.039,0.019,0.061,0.025,0.036,0.036,0.062,0.048,0.073,0.037,0.025,0.000,-0.007,-0.014,-0.050,-0.014,0.007,-0.035,-0.115,-0.039,-0.113,-0.102,-0.109,-0.158,-0.158,-0.133,-0.110,-0.170,-0.124,-0.115,-0.134,-0.097,-0.106,-0.155,-0.168,-0.038,-0.040,-0.074,-0.011,-0.040,-0.003,-0.019,-0.022,-0.006,-0.049,-0.048,-0.039,-0.011,-0.036,-0.001,-0.018,-0.037,-0.001,0.033,0.061,0.054,0.005,0.040,0.045,0.062,0.016,-0.007,-0.005,0.009,0.044,0.029,-0.016,-0.028,-0.021,-0.036,-0.072,-0.138,-0.060,-0.109,-0.064,-0.142,-0.081,-0.032,-0.077,-0.058,-0.035,-0.039,-0.013,0.007,0.007,-0.052,0.024,0.018,0.067,0.015,-0.002,-0.004,0.038,-0.010,0.056) 


V1=c(-0.083,-0.089,-0.042,-0.071,-0.043,-0.026,0.025,0.059,-0.019,0.107,0.049,0.089,0.094,0.090,0.120,0.169,0.173,0.159,0.141,0.157,0.115,0.128,0.154,0.083,0.038,0.081,0.129,0.120,0.112,0.074,0.022,-0.022,-0.028,-0.048,-0.027,-0.056,-0.027,-0.107,-0.020,-0.063,-0.069,-0.019,-0.055,-0.071,-0.027,-0.034,-0.018,-0.089,-0.068,-0.129,-0.034,-0.002,0.011,-0.009,-0.038,-0.013,-0.006,0.027,0.037,0.022,0.087,0.080,0.119,0.085,0.076,0.072,0.029,0.103,0.019,0.020,0.052,0.024,-0.051,-0.024,-0.008,0.011,-0.019,0.023,-0.011,-0.033,-0.101,-0.157,-0.094,-0.099,-0.106,-0.103,-0.139,-0.093,-0.098,-0.083,-0.118,-0.142,-0.155,-0.095,-0.122,-0.072,-0.034,-0.047,-0.036,0.014,0.035,-0.034,-0.012,0.054,0.030,0.060,0.091,0.013,0.049,0.083,0.070,0.127,0.048,0.118,0.123,0.099,0.097,0.074,0.125,0.051,0.107,0.069,0.040,0.102,0.100,0.119,0.087,0.077,0.044,0.091,0.020,0.010,-0.028,0.026,-0.018,-0.020,0.010,0.034,0.005,0.010,0.028,-0.043,0.025,-0.069,-0.003,0.004,-0.001,0.024,0.032,0.076,0.033,0.071,0.000,0.052,0.034,0.058,0.002,0.070,0.025,0.056,0.051,0.080,0.051,0.101,0.009,0.052,0.079,0.035,0.051,0.049,0.064,0.004,0.011,0.005,0.031,-0.021,-0.024,-0.048,-0.011,-0.072,-0.034,-0.020,-0.052,-0.069,-0.088,-0.093,-0.084,-0.143,-0.103,-0.110,-0.124,-0.175,-0.083,-0.117,-0.090,-0.090,-0.040,-0.068,-0.082,-0.082,-0.061,-0.013,-0.029,-0.032,-0.046,-0.031,-0.048,-0.028,-0.034,-0.012,0.006,-0.062,-0.043,0.010,0.036,0.050,0.030,0.084,0.027,0.074,0.082,0.087,0.079,0.031,0.003,0.001,0.038,0.002,-0.038,0.003,0.023,-0.011,0.013,0.003,-0.046,-0.021,-0.050,-0.063,-0.068,-0.085,-0.051,-0.052,-0.065,0.014,-0.016,-0.082,-0.026,-0.032,0.019,-0.026,0.036,-0.005,0.092,0.070,0.045,0.074,0.091,0.122,-0.007,0.094,0.064,0.087,0.063,0.083,0.109,0.062,0.096,0.036,-0.019,0.075,0.052,0.025,0.031,0.078,0.044,-0.018,-0.040,-0.039,-0.140,-0.037,-0.095,-0.056,-0.044,-0.039,-0.086,-0.062,-0.085,-0.023,-0.103,-0.035,-0.067,-0.096,-0.097,-0.060,0.003,-0.051,0.014,-0.002,0.054,0.045,0.073,0.080,0.096,0.104,0.126,0.144,0.136,0.132,0.160,0.155,0.136,0.080,0.144,0.087,0.093,0.103,0.151,0.165,0.146,0.159,0.156,0.002,0.023,-0.019,0.078,0.031,0.038,0.019,0.094,0.018,0.028,0.064,-0.052,-0.034,0.000,-0.074,-0.076,-0.028,-0.048,-0.025,-0.095,-0.098,-0.045,-0.016,-0.030,-0.036,-0.012,0.023,0.038,0.042,0.039,0.073,0.066,0.027,0.016,0.093,0.129,0.138,0.121,0.077,0.046,0.067,0.068,0.023,0.062,0.038,-0.007,0.055,0.006,-0.015,0.008,0.064,0.012,0.004,-0.055,0.018,0.042)

U2=c(0.022,0.005,-0.022,0.025,-0.014,-0.020,-0.001,-0.021,-0.008,-0.006,-0.056,0.050,-0.068,0.018,-0.106,-0.053,-0.084,-0.082,-0.061,-0.041,-0.057,-0.123,-0.060,-0.029,-0.084,-0.004,0.030,-0.021,-0.036,-0.016,0.006,0.088,0.088,0.079,0.063,0.097,0.020,-0.048,0.046,0.057,0.065,0.042,0.022,0.016,0.041,0.109,0.024,-0.010,-0.084,-0.002,0.004,-0.033,-0.025,-0.020,-0.061,-0.060,-0.043,-0.027,-0.054,-0.054,-0.040,-0.077,-0.043,-0.014,0.030,-0.051,0.001,-0.029,0.008,-0.023,0.015,0.002,-0.001,0.029,0.048,0.081,-0.022,0.040,0.018,0.131,0.059,0.055,0.043,0.027,0.091,0.104,0.101,0.084,0.048,0.057,0.044,0.083,0.063,0.083,0.079,0.042,-0.021,0.017,0.005,0.001,-0.033,0.010,-0.028,-0.035,-0.012,-0.034,-0.055,-0.009,0.001,-0.084,-0.047,-0.020,-0.046,-0.042,-0.058,-0.071,0.013,-0.045,-0.070,0.000,-0.067,-0.090,0.012,-0.013,-0.013,-0.009,-0.063,-0.047,-0.030,0.046,0.026,0.019,0.007,-0.056,-0.062,0.009,-0.019,-0.005,0.003,0.022,-0.006,-0.019,0.020,0.025,0.040,-0.032,0.015,0.019,-0.014,-0.031,-0.047,0.010,-0.058,-0.079,-0.052,-0.044,0.012,-0.039,-0.007,-0.068,-0.095,-0.053,-0.066,-0.056,-0.033,-0.006,0.001,0.010,0.004,0.011,0.013,0.029,-0.011,0.007,0.023,0.087,0.054,0.040,0.013,-0.006,0.076,0.086,0.103,0.121,0.070,0.074,0.067,0.045,0.088,0.041,0.075,0.039,0.043,0.016,0.065,0.056,0.047,-0.002,-0.001,-0.009,-0.029,0.018,0.041,0.002,-0.022,0.003,0.008,0.031,0.003,-0.031,-0.015,0.014,-0.057,-0.043,-0.045,-0.067,-0.040,-0.013,-0.111,-0.067,-0.055,-0.004,-0.070,-0.019,0.009,0.009,0.032,-0.021,0.023,0.123,-0.032,0.040,0.012,0.042,0.038,0.037,-0.007,0.003,0.011,0.090,0.039,0.083,0.023,0.056,0.030,0.042,0.030,-0.046,-0.034,-0.021,-0.076,-0.017,-0.071,-0.053,-0.014,-0.060,-0.038,-0.076,-0.011,-0.005,-0.051,-0.043,-0.032,-0.014,-0.038,-0.081,-0.021,-0.035,0.014,-0.001,0.001,0.003,-0.029,-0.031,0.000,0.048,-0.036,0.034,0.054,0.001,0.046,0.006,0.039,0.015,0.012,0.034,0.022,0.015,0.033,0.037,0.012,0.057,0.001,-0.014,0.012,-0.007,-0.022,-0.002,-0.008,0.043,-0.041,-0.057,-0.006,-0.079,-0.070,-0.038,-0.040,-0.073,-0.045,-0.101,-0.092,-0.046,-0.047,-0.023,-0.028,-0.019,-0.086,-0.047,-0.038,-0.068,-0.017,0.037,-0.010,-0.016,0.010,-0.005,-0.031,0.004,-0.034,0.005,0.006,-0.015,0.017,-0.043,-0.007,-0.009,0.013,0.026,-0.036,0.011,0.047,-0.025,-0.023,0.043,-0.020,-0.003,-0.043,0.000,-0.018,-0.075,-0.045,-0.063,-0.043,-0.055,0.007,-0.063,-0.085,-0.031,0.005,-0.067,-0.059,-0.059,-0.029,-0.014,-0.040,-0.072,-0.018,0.039,-0.006,-0.001,-0.015,0.038,0.038,-0.009,0.026,0.017,0.056)

V2=c(-0.014,0.001,0.004,-0.002,0.022,0.019,0.023,-0.023,0.030,-0.085,-0.007,-0.027,0.100,0.058,0.108,0.055,0.132,0.115,0.084,0.046,0.102,0.121,0.036,0.019,0.066,0.049,-0.011,0.020,0.023,0.011,0.041,0.009,-0.009,-0.023,-0.036,0.031,0.012,0.026,-0.011,0.009,-0.027,-0.033,-0.054,-0.004,-0.040,-0.048,-0.009,0.023,-0.028,0.022,0.090,0.060,0.040,0.003,-0.011,0.030,0.107,0.025,0.084,0.036,0.074,0.065,0.078,0.011,0.058,0.092,0.083,0.080,0.039,0.000,-0.027,0.035,0.011,0.004,0.023,-0.033,-0.060,-0.049,-0.101,-0.033,-0.105,-0.042,-0.088,-0.086,-0.093,-0.085,-0.028,-0.046,-0.045,-0.052,-0.009,-0.066,-0.073,-0.067,0.011,-0.057,-0.087,-0.066,-0.103,-0.075,0.003,-0.021,0.010,-0.013,0.021,0.020,0.084,0.028,0.127,0.050,0.104,0.097,0.075,0.021,0.057,0.095,0.080,0.077,0.086,0.110,0.054,0.016,0.105,0.065,0.046,0.047,0.072,0.058,0.092,0.063,0.033,0.087,0.036,0.049,0.093,0.008,0.064,0.068,0.040,0.049,0.035,0.042,0.045,0.021,0.056,0.007,0.026,0.067,0.046,0.088,0.084,0.070,0.037,0.079,0.065,0.074,0.077,0.023,0.094,0.061,0.096,0.068,0.067,0.091,0.061,0.069,0.090,0.046,0.057,0.011,-0.018,0.005,0.001,-0.023,-0.087,0.010,0.023,-0.025,-0.040,-0.059,-0.063,-0.075,-0.136,-0.078,-0.102,-0.128,-0.116,-0.091,-0.136,-0.083,-0.115,-0.063,-0.055,-0.080,-0.093,-0.099,-0.053,-0.042,-0.011,-0.034,-0.027,-0.042,-0.022,-0.008,-0.033,-0.039,-0.036,0.019,0.036,-0.002,0.000,-0.021,0.060,0.030,0.073,0.080,0.061,0.046,0.062,0.010,0.034,0.103,0.107,0.016,0.080,0.067,0.007,0.060,0.021,-0.026,0.008,0.051,0.030,0.001,-0.036,-0.047,0.000,0.006,0.006,0.013,0.009,0.019,0.009,-0.086,-0.020,0.018,0.039,0.014,0.011,0.052,0.031,0.095,0.047,0.065,0.114,0.086,0.102,0.037,0.039,0.060,0.024,0.091,0.058,0.065,0.060,0.045,0.031,0.062,0.047,0.043,0.057,0.032,0.057,0.051,0.019,0.056,0.024,-0.003,0.023,-0.013,-0.032,-0.022,-0.064,-0.021,-0.050,-0.063,-0.090,-0.082,-0.076,-0.077,-0.042,-0.060,-0.010,-0.060,-0.069,-0.028,-0.071,-0.046,-0.020,-0.074,0.080,0.071,0.065,0.079,0.065,0.039,0.061,0.154,0.072,0.067,0.133,0.106,0.080,0.047,0.053,0.110,0.080,0.122,0.075,0.052,0.034,0.081,0.118,0.079,0.101,0.053,0.082,0.036,0.033,0.026,0.002,-0.002,0.020,0.087,0.021,0.034,0.003,-0.021,0.016,-0.009,-0.045,-0.043,-0.020,0.027,0.008,-0.006,0.043,0.045,0.014,0.053,0.083,0.113,0.091,0.028,0.060,0.040,0.019,0.114,0.126,0.090,0.046,0.089,0.029,0.030,0.010,0.045,0.040,0.072,-0.033,-0.008,0.014,-0.018,-0.004,-0.037,0.015,-0.021,-0.015)


bindistances=c(1.37,1.62,1.87,2.12,2.37,2.62,2.87,3.12,3.37,3.62,3.87,4.12,4.37,4.62,4.87,5.12,5.37,5.62,5.87,6.12,6.37,6.62,6.87,7.12,7.37,7.62,7.87,8.12)
```

Then, as a representation of currents:

```
   AA=14 
    x11()
par(mfrow=c(4,1))
         plotSticks(x=seq(from=(1),
                          to=(377),
                          by=(1)),
                    u=U1,
                    v=V1,
                    yscale=ysc,xlab='',ylab='',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',col=(rep('black',384)))
         axis(side=1)
plotSticks(x=seq(from=(1),
                          to=(377),
                          by=(1)),
                    u=U2,
                    v=V2,
                    yscale=ysc,xlab='',ylab='',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',col=(rep('black',384)))

plotSticks(x=seq(from=(1),
                          to=(377),
                          by=(1)),
                    u=U2,
                    v=V2,
                    yscale=ysc,xlab='',ylab='',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',col=(rep('black',384)))
plotSticks(x=seq(from=(1),
                          to=(377),
                          by=(1)),
                    u=U2,
                    v=V2,
                    yscale=ysc,xlab='',ylab='',xaxt='n',yaxt='n',col=(rep('black',384)))
```

In order to simplify the representation, the three last plots are based on the same data.

Comment: levelplot is a lattice function, so look at `?llines`.

Comment: Post some data. Just posting a random matrix doesn't indicate what sorts of data layout you are working with. (I'm off to bed. Almost midnight here.)

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the long time before answering, and thank you for your help ! I'm currently editing the question with some data.

Comment: There, i added some data, i'm trying to make it with llines functions. Again, thank you!